# PlayFramework SignedData

Tags: scala, playframework

Появилась интересная ситуация, которая не может меня оставить равнодушным! На проекте с Play работаю 4 менсяца!

Poject:
JVM version:      Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_66 (25.66-b17) Oracle Corporation
Scala version:    2.11.1
Play version:     2.3.10

Ситуация:

В одном контроллере я обращаюсь java.security.Signature, 
конкретнее:

```
val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
signature.update(msgBytes)
val signedData = signature.sign
```

Когда доходит именно до этих строк, то код перестает работать! Он ничего не возвращает не выдает ошибку, просто не работает!

Гипотезы:

1. Где-то в Play блокируются некоторый функционал по каким либо причинам
2. Не вылетает ошибка, значит код не чувствует, что пошло что то не так!

Вопрос:

1. Где в Play посмотреть есть ли ограничения на библиотеки из соображений безопасности?
2. Каковы причины странного поведения Play?

Comment: если под linux, попробуйте мышь подвигать и на клавиатуре что-нибудь понабирать

Comment: Не вижу в коде ничего связанного с PlayFramework. В пустом проекте (без PlayFramework) падает с ошибкой. По ошибке находим решение, где говорится что перед тем как юзать `sign` надо его проинициализировать.
Ссылка на пример рабочего кода(проверена так же в Play 2.6, но по идее разницы вообще нету):
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1iH1TtbnSuWgAcfcscIuyg